# How to implement "SHOW COLUMN FROM (SELECT Result) WHERE Column_name = 'column_name'"?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

Good Evning My Brothers/Sisters.

I want to check whether a column is exist from select result.

I have tried some effort like below but instead it gives me an error.

```
SHOW COLUMNS 
    FROM (SELECT
                    hasil.skpd, hasil.kode_skpd, SUM(hasil.sudah_isi) AS sudah_isi, SUM(hasil.belum_isi) AS belum_isi
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            a.id_pegawai, c.skpd, c.kode_skpd, a.id_satuan_organisasi, a.nama_pegawai, a.nip,
                            CASE
                                WHEN i.id_pegawai IS NULL THEN 0
                                ELSE 1
                            END AS sudah_isi,
                            CASE
                                WHEN i.id_pegawai IS NULL THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END AS belum_isi
                        FROM
                            tbl_pegawai a
                            LEFT JOIN ref_skpd c ON a.id_satuan_organisasi = c.id_skpd
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_bapertarum i ON (a.id_pegawai = i.id_pegawai AND YEAR(i.tgl_lapor)='2015')
                        GROUP BY
                            a.id_pegawai
                    ) hasil
                WHERE
                    1 AND hasil.kode_skpd LIKE 'Badan Kepegawaian Daerah%'
                GROUP BY
                    hasil.id_satuan_organisasi
                ORDER BY
                    hasil.kode_skpd) WHERE Field = "kode_skpd"
```

This is the full error result:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT
                    hasil.skpd, hasil.kode_skpd, SUM(hasil.sudah_isi) AS s' at line 2
```

How do i to find the existence of a column or columns from SELECT result ?

Thanks in advance Brothers/Sisters.

Comment: SQL will complain if a column does not exist when you try to run it so are you trying to write a syntax/existence check prior to running code?

Comment: `select * from information_schema.columns i where i.TABLE_NAME in ('tbl_pegawai','ref_skpd','tbl_bapertarum');`

Comment: @P.Salmon : Yes i am sir. I want to check if field_name exist then will set a variable's value sir. Do you know how to do it in my case sir ?

Comment: @Luuk This is out of my case sir. I mean how do we check the existence of field_name from select result sir.